# How to run shell script without typing bash (bash command error:mapfile not found)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am using mapfile -t to obtain content of a text file and assign it to array.
In Jenkins it works fine where it will prompt steps and what command executed in console output .When I try to run in local console for example putty it prompts.

`mapfile: not found [No such file or directory]`

I know that mapfile is a bash command is and I am able to run the shell program after typing bash and executing the script.Is there anyway that I don't need to type bash in order to run the program ?I include `#!/bin/bash -x` on top of the script it still display the same error .The reason I don't want to type bash and execute the script is due to that it did not show what are the errors when the script dies.It did not display the error handling process that was in the script and it did not display output when it runs the command.

Comment: Which version of Bash?

Comment: How are you invoking the `mapfile` command? Copy paste the syntax

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov -4.2.25(1)-release

Comment: @Inian
#!/bin/bash -x
set -e
if [ $item= '-database' ]
then
      mapfile -t DATA< $DATA_FILES
fi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please open a new file called `script` in a text editor. Type your program in:

```
#!/bin/bash -x 
set -e
item=$1

if [ $item = '-database' ] then
    mapfile -t DATA < $DATA_FILES
fi
```

save the file, execute `chmod u+x` and then

```
./script "-database"
```

to run it.

That's it.

However, that script will print nothing.